# How to create in-app purchase to upgrade from free version to paid version android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing

I have two version of my app

1. Paid Version
2. Free Version

Now in free version I disabled some features that are available only in the paid version.
So what i want is when user taps on any of those disabled features, the in-app purchase window should pop up and when the transaction completes the free version of the app should get replaced by the paid version.

Can you please tell me what would be the right way to do that.

Answer (score 6):

**Free version to paid version scenario:**

> To understand why you should only go for in app billing inside free
>   version
>
> 1)
>   [Upgrading free to paid Android apps without leaving two icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130688/upgrading-free-to-paid-android-apps-without-leaving-two-icons)
>
> 2)
>   [Is it possible to replace an existing Android free app with its paid version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428381/is-it-possible-to-replace-an-existing-android-free-app-with-its-paid-version)

**Both case scenario:**

> 3)
>   [In app-billing implementation , buying paid app from free version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153297/in-app-billing-implementation-buying-paid-app-from-free-version)

After all it is your choice to select the way as you want to develop app but according to what I suggest:

you should go for the first option that you should provide all feature in the free app version only and upgrade your feature after simple product in app flow.

Hope you clear the way for the further development flow in your app.

Comment: can i buy another app i.e. the paid version of my app on google play from in app purchases from lite version.

Comment: no you can simply redirect the user to google play paid app link. and they will manually download the app from play store or other best option I have given in the link that you should lock feature for the free version app, and when user try to access that feature simply call in app purchase flow and after purchase successfully, allow user to access that feature.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use two versions if you are using in-App billing. Just use free version and implement in-app purchase in it. When user click on disabled features just open the in-app flow. If user complete the in-app purchase, just unlocked the features with in your free version. You also need to store user information on your server if user uninstall or change his device you will know that this user has already purchased your app. [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)  is the implementation of in-app purchase.