# Instant App - Install Full Version Popup?

Tags: android, instant

currently I'm implementing an instant app. I would like to enable the users to upgrade to the full version directly within the app like the google travle app does: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.travel.onthego

before clicking on install

[image]

after clicking on install

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509607/how-to-create-in-app-purchase-to-upgrade-from-free-version-to-paid-version-andro Check this out. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! However, my case is about instant apps, not inapp purchase.