# Tool for ease of using multiple Android markets?

Tags: android, design-patterns, google-play, amazon-appstore

Is there a library out there for easily maintaining an app on multiple Android markets?

Specifically, I'm looking for something that will:

1. Identify what market the app was sold on.
2. Handle in product apps
3. Figure out if the product is licensed.

I'm wanting to do this for at least the following marketplaces:

- Google Play
- Amazon App store

If there isn't one, then I'm planning on making one myself. I've been trying to figure out how to design such a tool. It seems to me the best way would be to either do a full blown Factory pattern, or perhaps a template for the concrete Classes to use, and a class that figures out what app market you are using, then passes the appropriate class to manage that object. Any thoughts?

Comment: _3. Figure out if the product is licensed._  See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384457/how-to-check-android-licensing-permission-of-other-applications).

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the 'market' by using `PackageManagergetInstallerPackageName()`, will be 'com.android.vending' for the Android Market/Play Store.

In-product apps are mostly incompatible and depend on adding stuff to the manifest, availability of third party apps (Play Store client or Amazon Appstore client, etc.) and you probably can't even run the same APK to support both Amazon and Google. In short, it's probably not possible or not worth the effort. Do share if go through with this tough.